# Hebrew Keyboard on Droid4X android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, languages, emulators

I want to run Android apps on the Droid4X Android emulator and I want to type Hebrew using my PC keyboard. When I use the emulator though, it only accepts english from my PC keyboard and there is no on-screen keyboard. Cut&paste Hebrew text is the only option which works (Hebrew text is displayed correctly after paste from Windows 10).

Any idea how can I enable my PC keyboard to use Hebrew within the Droid4X Android emulator?

Any other recommended Android emulator which supports foreign languages? (I use a Windows 10 PC).